# Issues with Displays on VMware. Scale missing + cannot permanently add resolution

Tags: display, vmware-player, 4k-monitor, hdpi

I have already spent some time to find solutions for my issues looking into ubuntu forums and google, but no viable solution.

I am using on Lenovo Ideacentre (with 4K display) VMware Player to run ubuntu (18.10). At the beginning I could set proper resolution 3160x2160 and use Scale to 200%. After some time it was gone and I have to use xrandr command everytime I restart the machine to bring back the resolution. However now the Scale option is gone in the Displays menu, wich makes working on a PC with 4k really difficult. Here am my two questions:
- How can I use xrandr command to set up my display permanently, i.e. that the screen resolution 3160x2160 stays after rebooting the system.

- How to bring back Scale into Displays?

Cheers,
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen 4K with native scaling will stay, as well as 200% scaling factor

- [VMWare options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfgIi.jpg)
- [Ubuntu VM properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ilHU.jpg)
- [gnome-tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q6AR.jpg)

As an alternative, install `gnome-tweaks` tool

```bsh
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

after install you can use [font scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q6AR.jpg) factor of 2.0